# geom_beeswarm and manually set colors (scale_fill_manual)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a beeswarm plot with the ggbeeswarm package (with `geom_beeswarm()`), and I want to MANUALLY fill the points with colors according to the factor levels in a factor variable. Also, I want to set the color around the points (to white).

Setting colors to `fill = [FACTOR]` inside `aes()` works fine; the points have different fill colors, and I can set the color of the line around the point to white like this `geom_beeswarm(color = "white")` (see code chunk #1 below). But when I want to manually set the fill color with `scale_fill_manual`, the `color = "white"` command in `geom_beeswarm()` seems to override it (see code chunk #2 below).

How can I a) set colors manually and b) color the line around my points white?

(All of this works fine with `geom_point()`, but I like `geom_beeswarm()` better.)

Here's some dummy data and code that illustrates it all:

```
# Provide minimal dataframe
x <- c(rep(c("A", "B"), 10))
y <- (rnorm(20, 2, 1))
z <- c(rep(c("Treatment", "Zero"), 10))

df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

# Draw beeswarm plot
library(ggbeeswarm)

# Works fine: (code chunk #1)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_beeswarm(color = "white",
            pch = 21)

# Does not work fine: (code chunk #2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
   geom_beeswarm(color = "white") +
     scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 21)) +
     scale_fill_manual(values=c("#104E8B", "#72bcd4"))
```

Comment: Chunk #2 doesn't work because you didn't map anything to shape as an aesthetic, & geom_beeswarm's default shape (19) uses color, not fill. Try putting `pch = 21` or `shape = 21` inside `geom_beeswarm()` & get rid of the shape scale (it's not doing anything there).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Z. Lin! That did the trick :-)

Comment: @Z.Lin please post as an answer.